# Flappy bird flap higher on longer press?

Tags: flappy-bird

Does Flappy Bird's bird flaps higher on longer press? I guess it is, but it might be just my perception.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Flappy bird flaps the same amount each time you tap the screen, no matter how long or hard you tap.

Source: personal experience

Comment: The only game I know of that does this is ironpants.

Comment: that game is horrible @Someguy112161